# Uninstall flux which was installed from source

Tags: python, display, uninstall, git, temperature

I installed Flux using following steps ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/548714/487265))

> 1. git clone https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet.git
> 2. cd f.lux-indicator-applet
> 3. sudo python setup.py install

Now I want to uninstall this application from my system. I tried looking for some script in the source which can help me, but I didn't find any. I am not sure if removing every file I find associated with this application will be a good idea.

What is the most appropriate way of uninstalling this application.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to nail down everything that is installed via `python setup.py install`. The best you can do is to remove manually where you think the installed files might be. They are most likely in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @edwinksl +1. some things to try are here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/38692/how-does-one-remove-applications-installed-through-python-setup-py-install